# Avahi on FreeBSD: Machine is Seen but Does Not See

Tags: freebsd, avahi, mdns

I have a FreeBSD 10.3 box with Avahi 0.6.31 which is visible to the other machines on my network, but which is itself unable to resolve any names in the `.local` domain. That is to say, all the other machines show up in `avahi-browse` and `avahi-resolve-host-name`, but `getent hosts <hostname>` returns nothing.

I have two other boxen on the same network: one Ubuntu 14.04 with Avahi 0.6.31, and one OSX 10.4 with mDNSResponder, both of which can resolve the FreeBSD box.

Both Avahi machines have identical `avahi-daemon.conf` files, and each machine's `nsswitch.conf` contains the line

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a solution, but after ignoring the problem for 5 years I upgraded to FreeBSD 11.4 and reinstalled avahi 0.8 from package, and the problem went away. I suppose it could have been a bug in the FreeBSD port of avahi 0.6.

Answer (score 0):

After months of this not working on my laptop, I realised the issue was firewalling ... that's on Linux, but I can imagine the same thing happening on any BSD.

Because I connect it to conf networks sometimes, having firewall rules seemed sensible. But if they block 5353/udp packets, then yeah mDNS isn't going to work when I'm at home.

No clue whether this was your problem 4-5y ago, but ... this result shows up high in "avahi sees no hosts". Hopefully my comment is going to help someone some day.